# SFSE Leaderboard extra scrollbar

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Would like to report a UI Issue in SFSE leaderboard in Chrome, works fine in Microsoft edge.

Looks like Erik broke something :D

[image]

Browser: `Chrome Version 62.0.3202.52 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)`

OS: `Windows 10 Pro | 64-bit`

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Latest stable Chrome, Windows 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwo3g.png - can you share your browser/OS and versions?

Comment: Added browser and OS details.

Comment: Chrome 62 is still in **beta**,  meaning it is not yet supported. I can not repro using the latest stable Chrome (61). Do you have any add-ons/extensions/user scripts installed? What happens if you disable them?

Comment: That make sense, tried opening in guest mode, still an [issue](https://imgur.com/a/ekFw3). Link I am trying is [this](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/213/alltime/salesforce). Weird thing is I use different users in Chrome, 2 users, both have extensions - Works fine in one, not in another. Also doesn't work in Guest mode.

Comment: I don't have an answer - this is not something we will fix, unless it still exists when Chrome 62 comes out of beta.

Comment: Yep, can understand. We can close this issue for now. I will try in different machines tonight!